# How to create a dynamic datagrid current cell changed event in wpf

Tags: wpf

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.CurrentCellChanged += new System.EventHandler(dgv_CurrentCellChanged);
private void dgv_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventHandler e)
{

}
```

But i am getting error how to Create dynamically in wpf

the error is

Error   2   No overload for `'dgv_CurrentCellChanged'` matches `delegate 'System.EventHandler'`

Answer (score 0):

this one:

```
private void dgv_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventHandler e) {

}
```

should be:

```
private void dgv_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

Comment: have u tried that? it's arguments so it should be EventArgs